# Angular 2 apply existing CSS class to a dynamic injected component

Tags: html, css, angular

I inject dynamically components to the DOM with:

```
let factory  = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component); 
let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], refDOM.parentInjector);
let comp     = factory.create(injector);
comp.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
refDOM.insert(comp.hostView,position);
return comp
```

I have a css class:

```
.vbox {

       display: -webkit-box;
       display:    -moz-box;
       display:         box;

       -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
          -moz-box-orient: vertical;
           -ms-box-orient: vertical;
               box-orient: vertical;


       display: -webkit-flex;
       display:    -moz-flex;
       display:     -ms-flex;
       display:         flex;

       -webkit-flex-direction: column;
          -moz-flex-direction: column;
           -ms-flex-direction: column;
               flex-direction: column;
}
```

I want to apply class vbox to the :host css tag of the dynamic injected component. Since the dynamic component isn't defined in the html file before being injected, I cannot apply existing class styles like: class="vbox".

Is it possible to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either inside the dynamic component add

```
@HostBinding('class.vbox')
isVboxClass:boolean = false; // or true by default
```

and then enable it using

```
comp.instance.isVboxClass = true;
```

or just

```
comp.location.classList.add('vbox');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to apply to the host tag itself the vbox class and not to the children of host. That is, I want to apply an existing style and not address existing elements of a class inside host. Thank you.

Comment: I see. Misunderstood the question. and you want to add it no matter what component `component` actually is?

Comment: Yes. Each dynamic component has it's specific css file defined in styleUrls. I define specific style rules inside the css file using the host tag, but, since rule vbox is used in other components, it is specified in other css file. When declaring the class explicitly in the html all works fine, but with dynamic components I cannot indicate explicitly to use the class vbox in the html.

Comment: You can also use `:host(.vbox) { ... }` then `...` will only applied when the class has the `vbox` class added. Does my answer above help solving your problem? I'm not sure from your last comment.

Comment: @HostBinding('class.vbox') works great. Is it possible to achieve the same only by CSS? That is, not including  @HostBinding('class.vbox') in the components code? Thank you.

Comment: I'm still unsure if I understand what you actually try to accomplish. `comp.location.classList.add('vbox');` allows you to do that without `@HostBinding()`

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. Dynamic component injection requires dynamic css binding. Thank you.